# Trouble with javascript "for" loop

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop

I have the following bit of code, which is supposed to write a series of triangles to a canvas element, but it appears to only go through the loop one time (only the first triangle is written to the canvas). I've looked at various similar questions, but am not having any success finding my problem, and was hoping a second pair of eyes might help.

I define array near the top of my script as follows:

```
var array = [0, 0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 0.8];

for (i = 0; i < array.length; i++) 
{
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(array[i],height);
    ctx.lineTo(((width*0.075) + array[i]),0);
    ctx.lineTo(((width*0.15 + array[i])),(height));
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.fill();
}
```

Thank you all for the responses. It turns out that I misplaced my parenthesis. (width * (0.075 + array[i])) and so-on is what was intended. The following is intended behavior, on a canvas that is about 210 px * 30 px.

```
var array = [0, 0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 0.8];

for (i = 0; i < array.length; i++) 
{
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(width * array[i], height);
    ctx.lineTo(width * (0.075 + array[i]),0);
    ctx.lineTo(width * (0.15 + array[i]),(height));
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.fill();
}
```

Comment: so you are defining `i` into global scope? srsly.. this does not help answering this question at all but you should never ever put stuff into the global scope.

Comment: "it appears to only go through the loop one time" - yeah, why would you expect anything else? You are looping through the array, once.

Comment: @GottZ if you don't use `"use strict";`, the loop executes without `i` being declared. http://jsfiddle.net/b826yj15/

Comment: Unless you have other code effecting it, the loop will execute 5 times.  (that is, the code inside the loop block) have you checked your console for errors?? what are you expecting that you arnt seeing?

Comment: If you can use ECMAScript 2015 (ES6), use `let` to declare `i` inside loop.

Comment: It actually does loop through 5 times, even with your code. It just draws the same triangle over the previous one.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It actually does iterate through 5 times, but it just draws the same triangle over the previous ones, because the values in the array are so small. Try it with larger values:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<canvas id="myCanvas" width="300" height="150" style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3;">
Your browser does not support the HTML5 canvas tag.</canvas>

<script>

var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");

var array = [0,40,80,120,160];
var height = 150;
var width = 300;

for (i = 0; i < array.length; i++) 
{
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(array[i],height);
    ctx.lineTo(((width*0.075) + array[i]),0);
    ctx.lineTo(((width*0.15 + array[i])),(height));
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.fill();
}

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

I took the basis for the code above from [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_canvas_beginpath) site because I've never used canvas before.

Answer (score -1):

try to use closure

```
for (i = 0; i < array.length; i++) 
{
(function(ind){
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(array[ind],height);
    ctx.lineTo(((width*0.075) + array[ind]),0);
    ctx.lineTo(((width*0.15 + array[ind])),(height));
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.fill();
})(i);
}
```

this should fix the problem.

Comment: I think this unnecessarily complicates the solution and it does nothing to address the fact the loop does run 5 times and it draws the triangle repeatedly on top of itself because the array dimensions are too small.